# in informatica - loop through based on different condition

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

in continuation to the question posted
[loop through based on different condition in informatica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76452451/loop-through-based-on-different-condition-in-informatica)

i am trying to find a way to loop through the set of entries  in informatica , if some condition is not met.
Below are the columns in each of the flat files

FF1 -> ID

FF2 -> ID, type, SecurityID

For the matching ID in FF1 and FF2 -  it checks for record  in FF2 which has value ,  type = P and for that corresponding record , lookup is done for  SecurityID column with tbl1.
if the match is not found in tbl1, it has to loop again for the same ID found in both flat files (FF1 and FF2) but now with type = C, lookup is done for  SecurityID column with tbl1 this time , now if the match is not found again...Null would get updated in the target table.

If the type is other than P and C, there is no loop as such it verifies if data in SecurityID column  is found in tbl1. if found , it updates target table, else value will be null in target table.

FF1

```
ID
===
1
2
3
```

FF2

```
ID |type |SecurityID
===================
1  |C    |S1
1  |P    |S2
1  |D    |S2
2  |B    |S3
2  |C    |S1
3  |P    |S2
3  |C    |S3
```

TBL1

```
SECURITYID |VAL
===============
S1         |10
```

OUTPUT IN TARGET TABLE SHOULD BE

TGT TABLE

```
ID |TYPE |VAL
============
1  |C    |10
1  |D    |Null
2  |B    |Null
2  |C    |10
3  |C    |Null
```

Comment: Ok, now this is far more readable and clear. Question: what have you tried so far? What issue are you facing? Have you designed a process? Please do not expect people to do the whole job - people here will gladly help overcoming issues. Btw, a hint: you don't need any loop in this process.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using joins.

You need to take `FF1`, `FF2`, and `TBL1`, and perform the following join

`FF1 INNER JOIN FF2` (since you're checking for matching ids only in both files), then again join with `TBL1` as the left join since you're only doing a lookup in that table.

Your final join would look like

`(FF1 INNER JOIN FF2) LEFT JOIN TBL1`

Upon this, you'll need to remove unwanted columns from the mapping and map needed columns to your target.

Just before your final target, you'll need to add a filter to filter out `P`s and `C`s, if they had `NULL` in the *val* column, i.e. they were not found in the lookup.